# Procedimento - Error code MySQL : #1064

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`

PROCEDURE `teste`(IN `pId` VARCHAR(20))NO SQL

INSERT INTO gpetnaold.pessoal SELECT * FROM gpetna.pessoal WHERE gpetna.pessoal.id=pId;

INSERT INTO gpetnaold.contato SELECT * FROM gpetna.contato WHERE gpetna.contato.pessoal_id=pId;
```

Alguém me pode ajudar com este erro.

Se colocar isoladamente qualquer uma das query funciona lindamente.
quando coloco as duas retorna o erro;

> erro 1064 'INSERT INTO gpetnaold.contato SELECT * FROM gpetna.contato
>   WHERE gpetna.contato.' at line 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a estrutura da sua procedure está errada, tente assim:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_da_proc (<seus parametros>)
BEGIN
    /* seu conteudo */
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funciona lindamente...

Comment: Caso minha solução atenda sua necessidade, peço a gentileza de marcá-la como solução aceitável (check verde) isso melhora minha reputação ;)